# Is it possible for azure logic app to receive a file from incoming http request?

Tags: azure, api, file-upload, httprequest, azure-logic-apps

I wanted to know if its possible to perform a file upload request to azure logic app's HTTP listener?
*I am not looking for built-in HTTP trigger which makes an HTTP call to the specified URL OR built-in HTTP action which makes an HTTP call to the specified URL*

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is through postman. Here is my logic app for your reference

[image]

postman request :-

[image]

Here is the output :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible for an Azure Logic App to receive files via an HTTP POST request. Here is the request body JSON schema to use in the Logic App:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "formdata": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "key": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "key",
                    "value",
                    "type"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        },
        "mode": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

The Python script below will send a request to the Logic App, including a dictionary of parameters and a separate dictionary associating each filename with its contents.

```
import requests
import pathlib

attachments = ["path/to/first_file.txt", "path/to/second_file.txt"] # Insert file paths
logic_app_url = "paste_logic_app_url_here" # Insert URL in quote marks

file_dict = {}
for filepath in attachments:
    file_dict[pathlib.Path(filepath).name] = open(filepath, 'rb')

payload = {"first_key": "first_val"} # Extra fields to include in your request
response = requests.post(logic_app_url, headers=None, data=payload,
                         files=file_dict)
```

I've run the request above, and it works. The request is received and processed by the Logic App. However, I haven't yet figured out how to parse the individual attachments in the Azure Logic App GUI. I think this may require a For Each loop as explained in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops). I hope this helps!